# tables - pick a cell when click on border

Tags: javascript, html, css

The idea is to have a grid and change color of any cell when you click on them. My solution was to make a table:

```js
var htmlElements = ""; // storing the whole table here

for (var r = 0; r < 40; r++) { // creating the table row by row
  htmlElements += '<tr>';

  for (var c = 0; c < 40; c++) { // and column by column
    htmlElements += '<td class="black" id="cell-' + r.toString() + '-' + c.toString() + '"></td>';
  }

  htmlElements += '</tr>'
}


var theTable = document.getElementById("tab");
theTable.innerHTML = htmlElements;

var allTableCells = document.querySelectorAll("td"); // adding all cells to an array

for (var i = 0; i < allTableCells.length; i++) {
  allTableCells[i].addEventListener("click", function() { // when click any cell
    let stringID = this.id.split('-');

    if (this.className == "black") {
      this.className = "white";
    } else {
      this.className = "black";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.white { background-color: white;}
        .black { background-color: black;}
```

```html
<table id="tab">

</table>
```

I need the cells to be small and that's a problem. When cells are too small you often miss and click on a border, so nothing changes. How can I pick the nearest cell when I accidentally click on a border? Maybe use canvas?

P.S. on this website -> https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/ you don't have that problem. I want my grid to be like that one

Comment: Your code doesn't work tho even if we click inside the cell.

Comment: Add one click event to the entire table instead of to each cell individually. Then you can use event.target to know which cell or other content thingy was clicked and can act accordingly. But elements that are too small to be clicked are usually not very user friendly, consider a different approach.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy edited,  now it works))

Comment: @Shilly could you please answer with a code snippet?

Comment: Your current code works for me, even when clicking on a border. The problem is that the squares are waaay too small to be clicked seperately inside your own snippt. The example you give has a table that is like 10 times bigger.

Answer (score 1):

On the website you attached, he is using a canvas, not a table.

If you want to stick to table, I guess you could try doubling the size of a cell when hovering over it, and then you will be able to catch the click.

I fixed your code up a bit as you can see in the following [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bknharqL/), I didn't touch your JS at all, since that wasn't your question.

> HTML

```
<table id="tab"></table>
```

> CSS

```
td {
  height: 1px;
}

tr {
  width: 1px;
}

td:hover {
  transform: scale(10, 8);
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is a bit more complex then what you are asking.
Imagine a `td` that has another `td` neighnour, 
while the border between two `td`'s is clicked, which one should be marked?

Also, There is not need to attach an event to each cell,
You can attach an event to table, and check the type of the target (see below).
I added an `IF` in the event listener, since clicking on the border, would actually select the table.

```js
var gridWidth = 40;
var gridHeight = 40;
var table = document.getElementById('grid');
for (var r = 0; r < gridHeight; r++) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(row);
  for (var c = 0; c < gridWidth; c++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(td);
  }
}
table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('black');
  }
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table id="grid"></table>
```